# Inconsistent behavior of Textblock in Silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

[image: Weird Behavior of Silverlight Textblock]

Hi all,

I found an issue with textblock in my Silverlight application. As observed from the picture I attached, in the "How to play" silverlight page, the title are bound to disappear if I navigate from different route.

Please note that that is static textblock with static wording. Just that from different navigation point, the header wording is missing!

I navigate from screen to screen using this.content = new something; (e.g. : this.content = new instruction())

Can someone guide me on how to overcome this issue? All my page is not usercontrol, but just silverlight page.

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="SpotTheDifference.UI.Game.Silverlight.instruction" 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
       d:DesignWidth="893" d:DesignHeight="670"
       Title="BonusLink Spot 'd' Difference">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Image x:Name="imgBG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="670" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="893" Source="/img/bg/dialogbox-bg.jpg" Visibility="Visible"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgPlayGame" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="731,209,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Source="/img/btn/btn_play_red.png"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnPlay" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="731,209,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Height="50" Opacity="0" Click="btnPlay_Click" MouseEnter="btnPlay_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnPlay_MouseLeave"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgScoreBoard" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="731,264,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Source="/img/btn/btn_scoreboard_red.png"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnScoreBoard" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="731,264,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Height="50" Opacity="0" Click="btnScoreBoard_Click" MouseEnter="btnScoreBoard_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnScoreBoard_MouseLeave"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgProfile" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="731,319,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Source="/img/btn/btn_profile_red.png"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnProfile" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="731,319,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Height="50" Opacity="0" Click="btnProfile_Click" MouseEnter="btnProfile_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnProfile_MouseLeave"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgHowToPlay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="731,374,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Source="/img/btn/btn_howto_green.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgLogOut" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="731,429,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Source="/img/btn/btn_logout_red.png"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnLogOut" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="731,429,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Height="50" Opacity="0" Click="btnLogOut_Click" MouseEnter="btnLogOut_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnLogOut_MouseLeave"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="lblDesc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,250,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="505" Height="195" Foreground="#FF007EFF" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontSize="14.667" FontWeight="Bold">
        <Run Text="There will be a set of 2 almost identical pictures revealed every month for players to identify 10 differences each."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="With every correct click, a circle will appear on the difference spot; whereas every wrong click, the timer will be further reduced."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="Total play time for this game is 30 seconds."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="(Hint: The faster you identify the differences, the higher the score)"/>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="lblHeader" Text="Spot 'd' Difference: How to Play Instruction" Margin="146,214,275,427" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontSize="21.333" FontWeight="Bold" Width="472" Height="29" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you show a bit of XAML?

Comment: @Tonio Added code for your reference

Comment: Ok it's navigation page content but i can't see the `Textblock`... Is `Text` property binded to the `Title` of navigation page ?

Comment: @Tonio : All my page having the same title "BonusLink Spot 'd' Difference" . <TextBlock x:Name="lblHeader" Text="Spot 'd' Difference: How to Play Instruction" Margin="146,214,275,427" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontSize="21.333" FontWeight="Bold" Width="472" Height="29" /> at the 3rd last line is the header that went missing, and it is not tied to the page title